# Trace messages from Website not appearing in Azure Diagnostics

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have an API deployed as an Azure Website (not a worker role).  The code for the site has Trace statements dotted through it that I would like to capture in an Azure Table via the Azure Diagnostics.

I'm using `Trace.TraceError`, `Trace.TraceInformation`, etc.

I've followed the instructions here, which essentially say that all that is required is to flick the switch in the management portal and set a location for Application Diagnostics: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

I have ensured that the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics reference is added to the project, and I have also tried adding the following to the Web.config (even though the instructions don't say this is necessary):

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" >
    <listeners>
      <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Despite this, the only output I get to the Azure Blob and/or Table (that I specified in the portal) is the following:

```
24/06/2015 14:02:49 AlasdairOTCDev  Verbose SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - process   11284   -1
24/06/2015 14:02:48 AlasdairOTCDev  Verbose SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - File.Copy 11284   -1
```

Trace levels are set to `Verbose` in the portal.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I debug this?

Many thanks for any assistance that can be provided as I'm rapidly running out of hair to pull out...

Comment: AFAIK, for Web Apps logging you don't need to add reference of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics` and make changes in web.config. Those are for Cloud Services. Once diagnostics is configured in the portal, everything should work just fine. Can you try by removing the reference and web.config changes?

Comment: It's the same behaviour with and without the reference and web.config values, but I've made sure they've both been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the root of the problem was with our build.

There was an issue where our build script was not compiling the TRACE symbol.  Builds compiled locally did include this (which is why it all appeared to work locally) but when we built and deployed to Azure it was being missed out.

Without the TRACE symbol, none of the logging statements were activated.

Comment: A year late, but you are a lifesaver...

IF anyone else is having a similar issue, switch to your development release profile and check the properties of your project. Make sure Build --> Define TRACE constant is checked

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the reference to **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics** in your project.  That is for Cloud Services and the article you referenced does not mention it since it is for Azure Web Apps (formerly Websites).

Assuming you are using an Azure Web App (not a cloud service web role), then you have to use the current Azure Management portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com if you want to configure your web app to store application diagnostics to an Azure Storage Table or Azure Storage Blob Container.  In the configure page for the web app, your configuration should look like this for a table storage.
[image]

*(Currently, the preview portal at https://portal.azure.com only lets you configure application diagnostics logging using the web app's file system)*

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I've done (per the link in the question).  I've removed the reference and the Web.config section but I still get the same result (i.e. only those snapshot entries in the table).
It doesn't make a difference whether I choose table, blob, or file system storage - same 'snapshot' entries and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still encounters this problem, besides for the excellent answers given on this page (enable tracing on azure, and making sure TRACE is set to true in your build), make sure you actually flush the traces!

In your code you need something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Can you see me?");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Flush();
```

Or

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true;
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Can you see me?");
```